# anyone know how angry bird simulate collision and casting?

Tags: android, collision-detection, collision

I am really interesting at how "Angry Bird" simulate the collision and casting.
If I want to implement the similar affect, what knowledge should I acquire ? Any references for that ?
Thanks very much !

Comment: hi, did you play "Angry bird" before ? As you need to throw a bird in the game.

Comment: @Thilo I think he means "casting" as a synonym for "throwing"

Comment: Got it. And I thought it was some cool physics engine lingo. Aren't they catapulted more than thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably using Box2D, like most 2D physics-based games these days. There are literally hundreds of ('twas rather shocking how popular this particular one became).

Here's an [example Birds-alike, with source](http://blog.anscamobile.com/2010/12/ghosts-vs-monsters-open-source-game-in-corona-sdk/) (Lua).

Comment: Thanks you, I have just download the code: https://github.com/ansca/Ghosts-vs.-Monsters. 
How can i import to Eclipse and run on Android ?